# warp MVP presenter inside viewmodel in android?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, mvp

one of mvp presenter pattern disadvantages is handling activity state or orientation change , while viewmodel survive orientation changes , so can i wrap presenter inside a viewmodel and still using MVP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course, have a presenter that lives inside a `ViewModel` to survive configuration changes, and live for the same time as the `Activity` or `Fragment` does.

You could also make your presenter itself the `ViewModel` subclass, or even use `MVVM` with the view component observing `LiveData` from the `ViewModel`, to be automatically safe with lifecycle handling at that point (as seen being pushed by Google recently).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, MVP MVVM and MVC are all just design patterns.
None of them inherently solve problems imposed by a particular platform.
They aim to provide a mechanism for developers to organize the structure of code into logical roles under the segregation of responsibility principle (see [SOLID software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).

The problem of state preservation in relation to configuration changes in Android Activities (Rotation is just one of these) is present as a feature of the Android operating system.
Google has built-in one solution to their Architectural components, which I presume you are referring to as `ViewModel` but that doesn't mean MVVM as a pattern supports it directly.

As mentioned by @zsmb13 , you can fairly cleanly use the viewmodel as a presenter.